# Azure powershell failing with error: One or more errors occurred while using Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to execute a powershell script in azure automation account runbook test pane. In my powershell script, I am importing the modules, connecting automation account using managed identity and then trying to get recovery services vault properties of a particular subscription using cmdlet "Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault"

**Powershell Script:**

```
Import-Module Az.Accounts
Import-Module Az.Resources
Import-Module Az.Compute
Import-Module Az.Automation
Import-Module Az.Storage
Import-Module Az.KeyVault
Import-Module Az.RecoveryServices

Connect-AzAccount -Identity

$context = Get-AzContext -ListAvailable
write-output "context" $context
Set-AzContext -Subscription "<<subscriptionID>>"
$vaultName = ""
$vaultResourcegroup = ""

$containerCtx = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $vaultResourcegroup 

write-output "containerCtx" $containerCtx
```

According to the above code, this should show the recovery service vault properties as I need a vaultId to get containerslist. Below is the error I am getting.

**error:**

One or more errors occurred.

Not sure if this is related to permissions on managed Identity?
[azure](/questions/tagged/azure)[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)[powershell-cmdlet](/questions/tagged/powershell-cmdlet) [azure-automation](/questions/tagged/azure-automation)

Comment: Add -Verbose to your cmdlets to get more detailed output, which might help identify where the issue lies.

and capture more detailed error information by redirecting the error output to a variable.



$containerCtx = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $vaultResourcegroup -ErrorVariable myError
if ($myError) {
    write-output "Error: " $myError
}

Comment: Ensure that the system-assigned managed identity is enabled for your Azure Automation account. The managed identity must have the necessary permissions to perform actions on the Recovery Services Vault. This includes permissions to read properties of the vault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I have got same error at first:

[image]

Then given the Back Operator role to managed identity of auto automation account to the Recovery Services Vault:

[image]

Later I used version also in scripts and it worked for me like below(modified yours script a bit):

```
Import-Module -Name Az.RecoveryServices -RequiredVersion 7.2
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$vaultName = "stackdemo"
$vaultResourcegroup = "rgname"
$containerCtx = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $vaultResourcegroup 
Write-output "containerCtx" $containerCtx
```

**`Output:`**

[image]